# can value field of input in ejs be edited like this?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to add value to the "value" filed of input dynamically
but this is not working.

```
        <form action="/assignCol" method="POST">
        <input
        type="RefCode"
        id="RefCode"
        name="RefCode"
        class="form-control"
        value="<%= user[i].id %>"
        readonly="readonly"
      />
      </form>
```

my aim is to provide the user with a feature to update the details of a person just by clicking the update button.
I want that once the user clicks the update button I could be able to send the user[i].id to the put API.

also, I want to send this user[i].id to the put API in the backend once I click this update button. so that in the backend I can fetch the data of that user with this id using req.body.id and find and edit the details of that user. is there any other possible way to do that?

Comment: do you mean you want to send ```PUT``` API request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the values at backend side then you must access the body object of `request` using `name` of `<input>` which is here `RefCode`

so it must be `req.body.RefCode`, to call the passed value

Secondly, you asked for another possible way of doing this, for simplicity I am changing properties name

```
 
        <input
        type="RefCode"
        id="refcode"
        name="refcode"
        class="form-control"
        value="<%= user[i].id %>"
        readonly="readonly"
      />
      <button onclick="updateData()"</button>


<script>
     const updateData = async () =>{
      const userId= document.getElementById("refcode");
      const result= await fetch(url, {
      method:'PUT', // You can also use POST here
      body:userId
      }
      console.log(result)
     }

<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using server-side rendering you should use `type="hidden"` instead of `type="RefCode"`.

An alternate approach is the Single Page Application (SPA). This approach removes the need for `server-side rendering` (no need for express to render HTML file on each request) and instead usage Ajax to and JSON API endpoints to implement the sight.

I would recommend [Angular - Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) if you like a taste of SPA.